# custom posts archive pagination links /page/2/ ends up in 404

Tags: pagination, links

I have a custom post named blog, I am using a page with url - slug blog, with custom template for displaying the blog arhive.

This is the query I am using in the template file:

```
global $wp_query;

        $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'blog', /*'cat' => $cat_id, */'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged ) );

        if ($wp_query -> have_posts()) {
            while ($wp_query -> have_posts()) { 
                $wp_query -> the_post();
                    echo '<div class="f4">';

                    echo '<div class = "left">';
                    echo '<a href = "'; the_permalink(); echo  '">';
                        echo '<div class = "image">';
                            the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail');
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class = "right">';
                    echo '<a href = "'; the_permalink(); echo  '">';
                        echo '<h3>'; the_title(); echo '</h3>';
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '<div class = "post-date">Posted on: '; echo get_the_date(); echo '</div>';
                    the_excerpt();
                echo '</div>';
            
            echo '</div>';
            };
        };
        wp_reset_postdata();
        // wp_reset_query();
        
        ?>
    </div>

</div>

<?php echo '<div class = "wrap blog-pagination">';
            the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2, 'screen_reader_text' => __( ' ', 'textdomain' ), 'prev_text' => __( '< PREVIOUS', 'textdomain' ),
            'next_text' => __( 'NEXT >', 'textdomain' ), ) );
        echo '</div>'; ?>
```

I am Using this script that generates the cpt - blog, and a default custom taxonomy for the blog.

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: blog and taxonomy
 Plugin URI: http://www.yashar.site/
 Description: A sample plugin to register blog CPT and blog_cat custom taxonomy and add a default category.
 Version: 1.0
 Author: Yashar Hosseinpour
 Author URI: http://www.yashar.site/
 */

namespace My_Plugin;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class Blog
{
    /**
     * Instance of Blog
     * @access protected
     * @var object $instance The instance of Blog.
     */
    private static $instance = null;

    /**
     * Blog constructor.
     * This is a private constructor to be used in getInstance method to do things in a singleton way
     * It's a good idea to leave this constructor empty and make `init` method public to use it outside of the class, which is a good thing for Unit Testing
     * @access private
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the plugin.
     * You can make it public and use it outside of the class
     * @access private
     * @return void
     */
    private function init()
    {
        // It's possible to use one method to cover these and hook it to `init`. I just like the way using single purpose OOP methods.
        // Note the priorities
        add_action('init', [$this, 'register_cpt'], 10);
        add_action('init', [$this, 'register_blog_cat_tax'], 11);
        add_action('init', [$this, 'insert_default_blog_cat_term' ], 12);

        // `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook is used. Doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/
        add_action( 'save_post_blog', [$this, 'set_default_blog_cat'], 99, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Register `Blog` CPT and `blog_cat` taxonomy to it
     * This should be done after `init`
     * @access public
     * @wp-hook init
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_cpt()
    {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => 'Blogs',
            'singular_name' => 'Blog',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Blog',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Blog',
            'new_item' => 'New Blog',
            'all_items' => 'All Blogs',
            'view_item' => 'View Blog',
            'search_items' => 'Search Blogs',
            'not_found' =>  'No Blogs found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Blogs found in Trash',
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => 'Blog'
        );
        $args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'blog_cat')
        );
        register_post_type('blog', $args);
    }

    /**
     * Register `blog_cat` taxonomy
     * This should be done after registering CPT
     * @access public
     * @wp-hook init
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_blog_cat_tax() {
        $labels = [
            'name'                      =>  'blog Categories',
            'singular_name'             =>  'blog Category',
            'all_items'                 =>  'All blog Categories',
            'edit_item'                 =>  'Edit Category',
            'view_item'                 =>  'View Category',
            'update_item'               =>  'Update Category',
            'add_new_item'              =>  'Add New Category',
            'new_item_name'             =>  'Category Name',
            'parent_item'               =>  'Parent Category',
            'parent_item_colon'         =>  'Parent Category:',
            'search_items'              =>  'Search blog Categories',
            'popular_items'             =>  'Popular Categories',
        ];
        register_taxonomy(
            'blog_cat',
            'blog',
            array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_tagcloud' => false,
                'hierarchical' => true
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Insert default blog_cat
     * `default_{$taxonomy}` option is used to make this term as default `blog_cat` term (non-removable)
     * @access public
     * @wp-hook init
     */
    public function insert_default_blog_cat_term()
    {
        // check if category(term) exists
        $cat_exists = term_exists('default_blog_cat', 'blog_cat');

        if ( !$cat_exists ) {
            // if term is not exist, insert it
            $new_cat = wp_insert_term(
                'Blog',
                'blog_cat',
                array(
                    'description'   =>  ' ',
                    'slug'          =>  'blog',
                )
            );
            // wp_insert_term returns an array on success so we need to get the term_id from it
            $default_cat_id = ($new_cat && is_array($new_cat)) ? $new_cat['term_id'] : false;
        } else {
            //if default category is already inserted, term_exists will return it's term_id
            $default_cat_id = $cat_exists;
        }

        // Setting default_{$taxonomy} option value as our default term_id to make them default and non-removable (like default uncategorized WP category)
        $stored_default_cat = get_option( 'default_blog_cat' );

        if ( empty( $stored_default_cat ) && $default_cat_id )
            update_option( 'default_blog_cat', $default_cat_id );
    }

    /**
     * Add an default `blog_cat` taxonomy term for `blog` CPT on save
     * If no `blog_cat` is selected, default blog_cat will be registered to the post
     * @access public
     * @wp-hook save_post_blog
     * @param integer $post_id
     * @param object $post
     */
    public function set_default_blog_cat($post_id, $post)
    {
        if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
            $blog_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'blog_cat' );
            $default_blog_cat = (int) get_option('default_blog_cat');

            if ( empty($blog_cats) ) {
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $default_blog_cat, 'blog_cat' );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instance
     * Used to retrieve the instance of this class.
     * @access public
     * @return object $instance of the class
     */
    static public function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance == NULL) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

// Run this
Blog::getInstance();
```

The problem is that the pagination links are not working. I mean the `/blog/page/2/` just end up with the 404 page.

link structure is set to: /%category%/%postname%/ and have to stay this way.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `WP_Query` in this context. WordPress has already queried the correct posts for that archive with the main query, and you only need to use the basic loop to display them:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) { 
        the_post();
        
        // Post markup here.
    };
};
```

Comment: I have to query the custom post type - blog, so I need to modify the query.

Comment: No you don’t. As I said, WordPress queries the correct posts automatically. You do not need to do this. In no documentation or decent tutorials are you ever told to do this.

Comment: The archive-blog.php does not get loaded, instead I use a regular page and assigned to it a custom template to query the blog posts.

Comment: The correct template would be is `taxonomy-blog_cat.php`